# Unable to open camera in android device - react-native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-video

**I am trying to implement live video streaming functionality using "react-native-nodemediaclient". And facing the issue in android device. It works properly in ios.**

**Unable to open the camera in an android device while using ignite boilerplate to manage project architecture. It's working properly in ios. When I'm creating using simple react-native it works in both android and ios.**

```
"dependencies": {
    "apisauce": "^0.14.2",
    "format-json": "^1.0.3",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "querystringify": "1.0.0",
    "ramda": "^0.26.1",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.57.8",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-config": "^0.10.0",
    "react-native-extended-stylesheet": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-nodemediaclient": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-permissions": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "6.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9",
    "react-navigation-redux-helpers": "^2.0.6",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.0",
    "reduxsauce": "0.7.0",
    "seamless-immutable": "^7.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "babel-plugin-ignite-ignore-reactotron": "^0.3.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^3.0.2",
    "enzyme": "^3.2.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.0",
    "eslint": "^5.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-eslint-comments": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.2",
    "ignite-animatable": "^1.0.2",
    "ignite-ir-boilerplate-andross": "^2.4.1",
    "ignite-redux-persist": "^1.1.2",
    "ignite-standard": "^1.0.0",
    "ignite-vector-icons": "^1.1.1",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "mockery": "^2.1.0",
    "react-dom": ">=16.3.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3",
    "reactotron-react-native": "^2.1.0",
    "reactotron-redux": "^2.1.0",
    "reactotron-redux-saga": "^2.1.0"
  }
```

Comment: Have you give camera permissions to the app?

Comment: @MtgKhaJeskai Yes, I gave it properly using react-native-permissions. Still unable to open camera in android.

Comment: @JaydeepPatel did you add this  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />` to your `AndroidManifest.xml` ?

Comment: @MohammedAlawneh As I told before I've added permissions properly. Also, it works properly when I don't use ignite boilerplate and simply create a project using a react-native command.

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli As simple as I told I've checked permissions after running it in my android device. And it is given perfectly to access camera and audio functionality. But as I told in the previous comment camera is not working due to ignite boilerplate. When I'm creating a project using simple react-native command and use react-native-nodemediaclient library for video streaming, the camera works perfectly.

Comment: @Jaydeep "It wasn't really simple" from the way you described your issue in your question body :) ... and if you really want to avoid unuseful comments .. I suggest you put more effort on improving your English :)